# label of input in materialize

Tags: input, label, materialize

I have a project with materializecss, and I would like to put the label of input when class="active" to the right of the input field . how to do this?

this is my code that label of input is on the left side of input tag

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
    <input id="name" type="text" class="validate wite right-align">
    <label class="color" id="name-label" for="name">Name</label>
</div>
```